# passing Jquery AJAX variables to PHP

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I'm quite new to Jquery AjAX thing, so I found this modal form from jquery UI and sadly the code would just append tables to the existing html document, what I want is to be able to pass such variables to php so I can use them for my database this is the link to the modal form -»
[jquery ui form](https://jqueryui.com/dialog/#modal-form)

I'm going to show my code anyway this is as far as I got:

```
var firstname = $( "#firstname" ),
        lastname = $ ( "#lastname" ),
        email = $( "#email" ),
        nickname = $( "#nickname" ),
        password = $( "#password" ),
        allFields = $( [] ).add( name ).add( email ).add( password ).add( nickname ),
        tips = $( ".validateTips" );

$( "#create-form" ).dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        width: 350,
        modal: true,
        show: "fold",
        hide: "fade",
        buttons: {
            "Create an account": function() {
                var bValid = true;
                bValid = bValid && checkLength( firstname, "firstname", 3, 16 );
                bValid = bValid && checkLength( lastname, "lastname", 3, 16 );
                bValid = bValid && checkLength( email, "email", 6, 80 );
                bValid = bValid && checkLength( nickname, "nickname", 3, 16 );
                bValid = bValid && checkLength( password, "password", 5, 16 );

                bValid = bValid && checkRegexp( firstname, /^[a-z ]+$/i, "First Name may consist of a-z" );
                bValid = bValid && checkRegexp( lastname, /^[a-z ]+$/i, "Last Name may consist of a-z" );
                bValid = bValid && checkRegexp( nickname, /^[a-z]([0-9a-z])+$/i, "Username may consist of a-z, 0-9, no underscores." );
                // From jquery.validate.js (by joern), contributed by Scott Gonzalez: http://projects.scottsplayground.com/email_address_validation/
                bValid = bValid && checkRegexp( email, /^((([a-z]|\d|[!#\$%&'\*\+\-\/=\?\^_`{\|}~]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])+(\.([a-z]|\d|[!#\$%&'\*\+\-\/=\?\^_`{\|}~]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])+)*)|((\x22)((((\x20|\x09)*(\x0d\x0a))?(\x20|\x09)+)?(([\x01-\x08\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x1f\x7f]|\x21|[\x23-\x5b]|[\x5d-\x7e]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(\\([\x01-\x09\x0b\x0c\x0d-\x7f]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF]))))*(((\x20|\x09)*(\x0d\x0a))?(\x20|\x09)+)?(\x22)))@((([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])*([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])))\.)+(([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])*([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])))\.?$/i, "eg. ui@jquery.com" );
                bValid = bValid && checkRegexp( password, /^([0-9a-zA-Z])+$/, "Password field only allow : a-z 0-9" );

                if ( bValid ) {
```

Everything above is untouched below is the code I added:

```
                    $.ajax({
                    url:'submit.php',
                    type:'GET',
                    data: { fname: firstname, lname: lastname },
                    success:function(data){
                            //$("#response").text(result);
                            alert("success!");
                        }
                    });
                    $( "#users tbody" ).append( "<tr>" +
                        "<td>" + firstname.val() + lastname.val()+ "</td>" + 
                        "<td>" + email.val() + "</td>" + 
                        "<td>" + password.val() + "</td>" +
                        "<td>" + nickname.val() +"</td>" +
                    "</tr>" ); 
                    $( this ).dialog( "close" );
                }
            },
            Cancel: function() {
                $( this ).dialog( "close" );
            }
        },
        close: function() {
            allFields.val( "" ).removeClass( "ui-state-error" );
        }
    });
```

So can you please help me?

Comment: Are you getting any error in the console or network tabs of the developer tools?

Comment: are firstname etc an input box reference or a string variable?

Comment: This code will append to the HTML <table> ALSO, but it should also send a request to submit.php. What data do you have in submit.php (try var_dump($_POST))? Are you seeing any errors in PHP/apache error logs/browser console?

Comment: yeah i got this error in my console "Uncaught RangeError: Maximum Call stack size exceeded but that's all

Comment: @Luke i tried to click submit but it doesn't submit now that i've added the ajax code

Comment: Clear your console, refresh the page to see if that error comes up again. If so, look deeper into the problem. Check which file and line number, and see if you can work out why the call stack was exceeded (maybe an infinite loop). Do you mean submit, or "Create an account"?

Comment: i dont really understand the thing written here but it says jQuery.extend.isArray @jquery.js: 458

Comment: and it keeps on repeating it's long you think this is an infinite loop?

Comment: it's long but it's no longer adding more..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as per your comment about the max stack size exceeded error, I believe your validations might be causing that issue. Let's try disabling them by commenting as follows:

```
                //bValid = bValid && checkLength( firstname, "firstname", 3, 16 );
                //bValid = bValid && checkLength( lastname, "lastname", 3, 16 );
                //bValid = bValid && checkLength( email, "email", 6, 80 );
                //bValid = bValid && checkLength( nickname, "nickname", 3, 16 );
                //bValid = bValid && checkLength( password, "password", 5, 16 );

                //bValid = bValid && checkRegexp( firstname, /^[a-z ]+$/i, "First Name may consist of a-z" );
                //bValid = bValid && checkRegexp( lastname, /^[a-z ]+$/i, "Last Name may consist of a-z" );
                //bValid = bValid && checkRegexp( nickname, /^[a-z]([0-9a-z])+$/i, "Username may consist of a-z, 0-9, no underscores." );
                // From jquery.validate.js (by joern), contributed by Scott Gonzalez: http://projects.scottsplayground.com/email_address_validation/
                //bValid = bValid && checkRegexp( email, /^((([a-z]|\d|[!#\$%&'\*\+\-\/=\?\^_`{\|}~]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])+(\.([a-z]|\d|[!#\$%&'\*\+\-\/=\?\^_`{\|}~]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])+)*)|((\x22)((((\x20|\x09)*(\x0d\x0a))?(\x20|\x09)+)?(([\x01-\x08\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x1f\x7f]|\x21|[\x23-\x5b]|[\x5d-\x7e]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(\\([\x01-\x09\x0b\x0c\x0d-\x7f]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF]))))*(((\x20|\x09)*(\x0d\x0a))?(\x20|\x09)+)?(\x22)))@((([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])*([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])))\.)+(([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])*([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])))\.?$/i, "eg. ui@jquery.com" );
                //bValid = bValid && checkRegexp( password, /^([0-9a-zA-Z])+$/, "Password field only allow : a-z 0-9" );
```

and let the execution flow and perform the ajax call. if you get an response from your php server then the problem is in the validations.

## edit

then the problem must be that you are passing the DOM objects as get parameters and jquery might be trying to serialize more than its able to handle, so let's try this:

replace:

```
type:'GET',
data: { fname: firstname, lname: lastname }
```

with:

```
type:'POST',
data: { fname: firstname.val(), lname: lastname.val() }
```

Comment: okay i tried to disable the validations but still the same then i disabled the                                        $.ajax({
      url:'submit.php',
      type:'GET',
      data: { fname: firstname, lname: lastname },
      success:function(data){
        //$("#response").text(result);
        alert("success!");
       }
      });                                                                    then it became functional again the thing is just it again just puts a table on the html and i'm still unable to fetch the data

Comment: do you have any idea how would i view the data? i switched submit.php to index.php because the jquery ui doesn't redirect me there then i tried this                                success:function(data){
        $("#response").text(data);
        alert("success!");
       }                                                          then i get the entire html code of index.. help :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass the value of the input elements :

`data : { fname: firstname.val(), lname: lastname.val() }`

and I would say you also need to encode them :

```
data : { fname: encodeURIComponent(firstname.val()), 
         lname: encodeURIComponent(lastname.val())
       }
```

You should also change the method to `POST` instead of `GET`. `GET` methods should be used to get data, not to post them. Also there are differences like POST is not cached, POST have no length limitation (in theory), POST is not added to the URL as `&param&param` and more.

Simply change to

```
$.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  ...
```

now in `submit.php` you can target the values as

```
$firstname = urldecode($_POST['fname']);
$lastname = urldecode($_POST['lname']);
```

From here you should not have any problems adding the rest of the values to `data : {}` and use them in `submit.php` too.

Comment: thank you so much david i don't understand the encodeURIComponent.. what does it do?

Comment: You are welcome! `encodeURIComponent` encodes parameters so they can be passed in an URL, used in a header and so on. That means converting whitespaces to `%20`,  @ to `%40` etc. See -> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent

Comment: thank you david.. anyway right now i'm still trying to figure out how to get the data since it doesn't redirect me to the submit.php anyway ill try to figure things out.. thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Ajax can do this. Google it, and check out api.jquery.com and look at the ajax functions, .ajax(), .post(), .get(), .load(), etc. credit:ExplosionPills

Here is what you would do:

```
 //Javascript file
$("input[type=checkbox]").click(function () {
$.post('my_ajax_receiver.php', 'val=' + $(this).val(), function (response) {
  alert(response);
});
});

//PHP file my_ajax_receiver.php
<?php
 $value = $_POST['val'];
 echo "I got your value! $value";
?>
```